# Can we use SPL time functions inside C++ operators?

Tags: ibm-streams, infosphere-spl

I want to use toTimestamp function inside cpp.So I am accessing it like SPL::Functions::time::toTimestamp(Sys.YYYYMMDDhhmmss,date).Problem is that its unable to recognize 'Sys'. What library should I include?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the `toTimestamp` family of functions were designed to be called by SPL code, they're not easy to use directly in C++. (The reason being that they rely on generated tuple and enum types.) From C++, it's easier to use the [`timeStringToTimestamp`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSCRJU_4.3.0/com.ibm.streams.toolkits.doc/spldoc/dita/tk$spl/fc$spl.time.html#spldoc_functions__timeStringToTimestamp.rstring.rstring.boolean) family of functions.